# Почему в данном предложении не стоит запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: Глаза её сияли, несмотря на то что ей смертельно хотелось спать. 
Мне хотелось поставить запятую так:"...несмотря на то, что ей смертельно хотелось спать", но мне сообщили, что тут её ставить не надо. Почему? Или я прав?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО(,) ЧТО**, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_483)

> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом ***несмотря на то(,) что***, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться, в этом случае запятая обычно ставится и перед союзом (перед словом «несмотря»), и между его частями (перед словом «что»).
>
> *Зритель должен был поверить, что перед ним человек, остающийся невредимым, **несмотря на то что** сквозь него пропускают токи необычайной силы.* Ю. Олеша, Зрелища.

***Глаза её сияли, несмотря на то что ей смертельно хотелось спать.***

Запятая в этом предложении ставится перед целым союзом ***несмотря на то что*** по следующему правилу:

> Если придаточная часть предложения следует за главной – запятая ставится только перед союзом.

См.: [**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ В КОНСТРУКЦИЯХ С СОСТАВНЫМИ ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ СОЮЗАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)

Есть в этом правиле такой пункт: ***...союз расчленяется... если...***

> автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение: *Мужики тихи, робки и вежливы **оттого, что** у каждого для весу в кудели по камню…* М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша. *Я спросил у отца, что значит «особенный вечер». Отец объяснил мне, что этот вечер называется так **потому, что** он не похож на все остальные.* К. Паустовский, Сказочник.

Думаю, что в Вашем предложении такое ударение будет излишним.

Comment: *в этом случае запятая **обычно** ставится и перед союзом (перед словом «несмотря»)* — немного странная формулировка.Перед словом "несмотря" запятая не ставится только в том случае, если оно стоит в начале предложения. [Александр, это не в Ваш огород камень (ответ я поддержал)].

Comment: @grizzly  Спасибо!  Видимо Грамота хотела акцентировать внимание на том, что при разделении других составных союзов первая их часть не отделяется запятой, а в случае с "несмотря" запятая ставится в подавляющем числе примеров. Отсюда, наверно, и это **обычно**.